# Cygwin wants to downgrade my Perl

Tags: perl, cygwin, downgrade

I'm using Cygwin 2.769.  I used `setup.exe` to upgrade Perl to version 5.14.1-2, which works fine.  But now whenever I open `setup.exe` to upgrade/install some other package, it by default wants to downgrade Perl back to 5.10.1-5.  If I don't remember to manually cycle that box over to my current version each time, Perl gets downgraded without my noticing.

Is this expected behavior, or have I hosed something up?  It seems like using the "Curr" setting should not by default downgrade things.

Comment: You'll likely get a quicker answer on the [Cygwin list](http://cygwin.com/lists.html#cygwin)

Comment: I just ran `setup.exe` myself.  The current version of Perl for Cygwin is 5.10.1-5.  How did you upgrade to 5.14.1-2?

Comment: There are two votes to migrate this to serverfault; wouldn't superuser make more sense?

Comment: You're probably right - I haven't used either of those communities much but perhaps that's a better fit.

Comment: I'm not at my work computer now, but I'm certain all I did to get the newer perl was click the version number until 5.14 showed up.

Comment: @Keith - and also that I didn't naturally think of "server" or "super" when thinking of my Windows box. =)  Anyway, I've now voted to migrate it too.

Comment: @KenWilliams: I was *sure* I had just tried that and it didn't work, but now it does.

Comment: Wait, was this migrated, or just killed?  I've never been through this process before.

Comment: This was just killed. Which, personally, seems odd: even if it's a better fit on one of the other sites, I don't think it's so horrendously off-topic to just die. In any case, as @Jim said, I suspect you'll have better luck with this one on the Cygwin mailing list.

Comment: He's probably right, but I'm growing tired of signing up for mailing lists, even in lurker mode, just to ask a question.  I'm probably on a couple dozen such mailing lists right now, and I need to stop.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem, and it's made package managers almost unbearable. When disparate packages want to rely on different versions of a package that can only install in one version at a time, bad things happen.

Don't use the system perl for anything. Install a perl that other packages don't care about.

Comment: I may do so.  But it would also be nice if Cygwin changed its behavior from insane to sane.